# Car only starts sometimes

Tags: starting, mitsubishi

My 2003 V6 Mitsubishi VRX Series 2 Diamante Has an issue where sometimes it starts fine and other times it will crank but wont catch, it’ll just sit there making a “nenenene” noise like its waiting to catch. the stereo and windows and lights will still work so i don’t think its the battery. I’m not sure why it does this, and only does it sometimes. I’ve been told it could be the fuel pump, or the alternator or the spark plugs. But i dont know much about cars and would like some advice before i take her into the choppy to get looked at?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know for sure as it's hard to diagnose something like this, but I'd lean towards the fuel pump before I'd even *think* it might be the other two things you'd mentioned. Have you had it checked for codes? Is the check engine light on?

Comment: Here’s a test. If you turn key to on (not start), and then wait ten seconds before turning it to start, does it always then start up reliably?  One failure I’ve seen is bad check valve at in tank fuel pump. After car is parked fuel line drains back to tank. Pls check?

Comment: Welcome.  Fuel flow would be a possible issue.  But tell us more than the noises.  Like the mileage.  Time/miles since tune-up. Any recent change in fuel economy.  Things like that.  I am not familiar with this model, but with more info maybe someone who is may have some model specific knowledge.  Consider going to a car parts store which offers a free scan, and see if there are any ODBII (oh dee bee two) codes which might be relevant.

Comment: I like @zipzit suggestion.  But do consider an error code scan.